# How to populate cumulative max records from the table without using OLAP function?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table like below

```
Id startdate enddate rate

1 1/1/2015 2/1/2015 10
1 2/1/2015 3/1/2015 15
1 3/1/2015 4/1/2015 5
1 4/1/2015 5/1/2015 10
1 5/1/2015 6/1/2015 20
1 6/1/2015 7/1/2015 30
1 7/1/2015 8/1/2015 10
1 8/1/2015 9/1/2015 30
1 9/1/2015 12/31/2015 20
```

I need to populate cumulative max values for each id (Id=1 for this example) including the first record, like below (SQL server 2008):

```
Id startdate enddate rate

1 1/1/2015 2/1/2015 10
1 2/1/2015 3/1/2015 15
1 5/1/2015 6/1/2015 20
1 6/1/2015 7/1/2015 30
1 8/1/2015 9/1/2015 30
```

Can any one help me on this?

Comment: I don't understand why you don't want to keep id = 4 where the rate is 10 but you keep line id = 1 where the rate is 10 too. What do you mean by "max values" and "min values"?

Comment: You can use SQL max function to get max value from your table .:)

Comment: The OP seems to clearly want the sequence of records that have the cumulative max.  I'm not sure why the question is getting downvotes.

Comment: Hi Guys, I need cumulative max for the above mentioned table. In teradata by using max(rate) over (order by start_date rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) we can get the desired out put Currently I am working on sql server 2008 and it is new to me.as per my knowledge sql server 2008 will not support the max(rate) over (order by start_date rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding). Can any one help to get cumulative max for the above table (I need first record as well) with out using OLAP functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to get the sequence of records with the max value at any given time.  You can do this by calculating the cumulative max and then comparing to the original value.  In SQL Server 2008, this can be accomplished with `outer apply`.

Here is how to express the query:

```
  select t.*
  from likebelow t outer apply
       (select top 1 max(rate) as maxrate
        from likebelow t2
        where t2.id < t.id
       ) tmax
  where tmax.maxrate is null or tmax.maxrate < t.rate;
```

Comment: Thank you very much Gordon Linoff.

Comment: Hi Gordon Linoff, I need to populate cumulative max for each id not for t2.id<t.id. Sorry for the confusion...I have modified the table data.